# SQLite Exists Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, logcat, db-browser-sqlite

I want to display all the data from my database created in [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), but I get these errors. I cannot find a solution. Please help me, this is very important to my project. Maybe there's a typo mistake.

```html
05-27 13:54:22.584 32610-32610/com.example.andre.nutridian E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.andre.nutridian, PID: 32610
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.andre.nutridian/com.example.andre.nutridian.Main2Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
        at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:201)
        at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:172)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.initWindowDecorActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:145)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onPostResume(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:267)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:172)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6362)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3336)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

My classes are DBHelper:

```html
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH="";
    private static String DB_NAME="test.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private Context mContext=null;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=16)
            DB_PATH=context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir+"/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH="/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";

        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(mDataBase!=null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }catch(Exception ex){}
        if(tempDB!=null)
            tempDB.close();
        return tempDB!=null?true:false;
    }


    public void copyDataBase() {
        try {
            InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outputFileName=DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput=new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

            byte [] buffer=new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length=myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openDataBase(){
        String path=DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
        mDataBase=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void createDataBase(){
        boolean isDBExist=checkDataBase();
        if(isDBExist)
        {

        }

        else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try{
                copyDataBase();
            }catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }

    public List<Aliment> getAllAlim(){
        List<Aliment> temp=new ArrayList<Aliment>();
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c;
        try {
            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Aliment", null);
            if (c == null) return null;

            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                Aliment aliment = new Aliment(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("aliment")), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("calorii")), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cantitate")));
                temp.add(aliment);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        db.close();
        return temp;

        }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

The MainActivity is:

```html
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Aliment> lstAlim=new ArrayList<Aliment>();
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    Button btnAfiseazaLista;
    LinearLayout container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        btnAfiseazaLista=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAfiseazaLista);
        container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

        dbHelper=new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        dbHelper.createDataBase();

        btnAfiseazaLista.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lstAlim=dbHelper.getAllAlim();
                for(Aliment aliment:lstAlim){
                    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
                    TextView txtAliment=(TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.txtAliment);
                    TextView txtCalorii=(TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.txtCalorii);
                    TextView txtCantitate=(TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantitate);

                    txtAliment.setText(aliment.getAliment());
                    txtCalorii.setText(aliment.getCalorii());
                    txtCantitate.setText(aliment.getCantitate());

                    container.addView(addView);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

These 2 are the classes I use, the [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) says in these 2 classes are the problems. I am new to this and I need a little guidance to resolve my errors. Please help me in any way. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Tha'erM.Al-Ajlouni I posted all the code because I thought it would help others, just in case. I know that posting so much code it's hard for reading

Comment: It's simple, read the logcat `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer`

Comment: @H.Brooks Can the problem be if I use API16 and the code is for API17?

Comment: @Ada look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with your SQLite Database.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
```

The issue is that you are declaring a `LinearLayout` but it's not a `LinearLayout`.

Make sure that `R.id.container` is actually a `LinearLayout` In your xml layout.

Try changing:

```
container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
```

To:

```
container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container);
```

Comment: you were right! In my xml file I had the id written wrong. It works now. Thank you so much